# How to get django models field value from model object in template tags

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

**Models.py:**

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
    version = models.TextField(blank=True)
    team = models.TextField(blank=True)
    project = models.TextField(blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(db_column='Notes', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    s = models.TextField(blank=True)
    send_mail_to = models.TextField(blank=True)
    send_mail_cc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'discussion'
```

**views.py:**

```
 p=Discussion.objects.filter(version=m2)
 return render_to_response('report/t2',{"p":p})
```

**Template(html):**

```
 <tr>
      <td width="20%" class="scratchblackfont12">Release Name :</td>
      <td><div style="overflow:auto"><input name="Release Name (if any ):" autocomplete="on" type="text" class="scratchsearchfield" elname="defaultFocus" id="r1" value="{{p.version}}"  READONLY multiline="true" ></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

But the template displays Nothing.Please help me to solve this problem.I want to get the model field value from model object in template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the `p` that you're sending to your view is a QuerySet, not an object instance. Try the following:

```
{% for p_object in p %}
<tr>
    <td width="20%" class="scratchblackfont12">Release Name :</td>
    <td><div style="overflow:auto"><input name="Release Name (if any ):" autocomplete="on" type="text" class="scratchsearchfield" elname="defaultFocus" id="r1" value="{{p_object.version}}"  READONLY multiline="true" ></div>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If you'd like to send a specific `p` object instance you'd have to do the following in your view:

```
p = Discussion.objects.get(version=m2)
```

but note that `get` will throw an error if the query returns more than a single object with version=m2.

Comment: Good answer @rolling stone. I completely missed the fact that he was using filter instead of get. I'm going to stop answering questions so late :)

Comment: @Brandon haha you should see some of the other answers I give late at night!

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you've referenced Discussion1, which isn't the name of your model (Discussion). It's also not obvious where the value of m2 gets assigned.

I would verify that:

```
objects = Discussion.objects.filter(version=m2)
```

returns objects from the shell. At the minimum, you'll get an empty list.

It helps us out a lot if you format your code properly, in addition to providing enough context so we can tell where things come from, what's what and so on, in order to provide answer.

Comment: Hi brandon discussion1 is a typo mistake.m2 is a variable contains version value. i try it in shell it works correctl.Please help me how can i get it in template

Comment: p = Discussion.objects.filter(version=m2)
returns a list of objects. so p[0].'version' gives the desired result.Since for me i Always required single object as a return type I use

p = Discussion.objects.get(version=m2)

in template i use {{p.version}} It works. Thanks Brandon for spending time for me